# Relationship between the validity of mean field treatment and the strength of coupling/interaction

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

Mean field is a quite common treatment in studying phase transition and critical phenomena, although it neglects fluctuations.  Imagine we have a Hamiltonian consists of free part and interaction part:
$$H=H_0 + H_{int}$$

My naive understanding of this approach is that:

Within the mean field treatment, we are essentially trying to describe the problem in a "single particle picture", where the effect of the inter-particle interaction is replaced by a background (constant) mean field. The elementary excitation of the mean field Hamiltonian (propagating mode) is not drastically different from the free Hamiltonian's modes (e.g. Bogoliubov quasiparticles). Physically, this makes sense if the interaction is not large (e.g. compared to the bandwidth of free electrons). However, when the interaction strength is very large, there might be a qualitative change of the elementary excitations, which might be absolutely different from the free part of the Hamiltonian.

Here I want to ask whether there is a mathematically rigorous way to tell if the mean field method is more suitable for weak coupling regime. I have managed to see this using a path integral formalism to represent the partition function. By doing a Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation, we can introduce the auxiliary field $\Delta$(order parameter). However, I couldn't see the relationship between the interaction strength and the validity of choosing a saddle-point solution of the effective action $S[\Delta]$ (I know the large-$N$ limit can validate the saddle point, but it seems here the coupling constant does not play the role of $N$).

Hope some experts can share some understanding about this. Thanks in advance.